# Unity touch events in the editor? (new input system)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get touch events in the editor. However I'm not getting any events from the input action.

I have a very simple script:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch;
 
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputAction _touch;
 
    void Awake()
    {
        TouchSimulation.Enable();
 
        _touch.started += OnTouch;
        _touch.performed += OnTouch;
        _touch.canceled += OnTouch;
    }
 
    void OnTouch(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        Debug.Log(context.ReadValueAsObject());
    }
}
```

So a simple `InputAction _touch` and I subscribe to all its events.
I also enable touch simulation in the Awake function using `TouchSimulation.Enable()`.

Then in the inspector I set it up like this:

[image: Inspector]

The settings of the Input Action are:

[image: Input Action]

And those of the Primary Touch are:

[image: Primary Touch]

When I click and drag my mouse in the game view nothing happens, no events are fired.

What am I doing wrong? What more do I need for getting touch events and simulating them in the editor?

I'm running Unity 2019.4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, apparently you need to enable the input action first:

```cs
void Awake()
{
    _touch.started += OnTouch;
    _touch.performed += OnTouch;
    _touch.canceled += OnTouch;
    _touch.Enable();
}
```

It might also be a good idea to enable/disable in the `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` callbacks for the monobehavour.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Touch.html

> Touch Simulation Touch input can be simulated from input on other
> kinds of Pointer devices such as Mouse and Pen devices. To enable
> this, you can either add the TouchSimulation MonoBehaviour to a
> GameObject in your scene or simply call TouchSimulation.Enable
> somewhere in your startup code.
>
> ```
> void OnEnable()
> {
>     TouchSimulation.Enable();
> }
> ```
>
> **In the editor, you can also enable touch simulation by toggling "Simulate Touch Input**
> **From Mouse or Pen" on in the "Options" dropdown**
> **of the [Input Debugger](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Debugging.html).**
>
> TouchSimulation will add a Touchscreen device and automatically mirror
> input on any Pointer device to the virtual touchscreen device.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work either. I also read that as that you have two options in the editor. Either case, neither seems to work. The difference I do see is that when using the debugger's options the "Simulated Touchscreen" device is always there, but when using code it only shows that device for a fraction of a second and then disappears again.